# PHP package won't install correctly

Tags: linux, debian, apt, php

Yesterday I did `apt-get upgrade` on my Debian/testing and broke a php5 package. I
even tried to remove & purge with `apt` and `dpkg clean apt cache`. When installed  again clean, it fails with following error message:

```
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.3.6-12) ...
readlink: invalid option -- 'm'
BusyBox v1.17.1 (Debian 1:1.17.1-10) multi-call binary.

Usage: readlink [-fnv] FILE

Display the value of a symlink

Options:
        -f      Canonicalize by following all symlinks
        -n      Don't add newline
        -v      Verbose

ucf: Unable to determine The new file
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Any ideas how to solve this Debian way?

Comment: The postinst script is invoking the Busybox `readlink` instead of the GNU version. What I don't understand is how it can happen. If you run `readlink --help` in a terminal, does the first line show `BusyBox` or `GNU coreutils`? What is your `PATH`? Did you knowingly do anything BusyBox-related? What Debian architecture are you running?

Comment: actually i did work with busybox some time ago , i was building initramfs & kernel with busybox for an embedded platform but do not recall changing anything on the system itself. this is a debian/testing running in a vbox

Answer (score 4):

You have accidentally changed `/bin/readlink` to be busybox, rather than the GNU coreutils version.

This will cause a LOT of breakage.  You need to restore GNU coreutils.

Try

```
# aptitude reinstall coreutils
```

Comment: did not help, any other ideas? :)

Comment: solved! for some reason i've had busybox binary called /usr/bin/readlink and when executed readlink in shell busybox readlink was launched instead. little gdb session and i've figured that out .. after that i removed the mentioned binary from /usr/bin and reinstalled coreutils pkg .. boy, do i feel foolish now :) thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the post install script is broken. Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php5.postinst` and look for the line referencing `readlink` and see what you can do to fix it.

Afterward run `apt-get upgrade` again.

Comment: The postinst is not broken.  It assumes `readlink` is the GNU readlink, which is provided by the `coreutils` package, which is `Essential: yes` and `Priority: required`, so this is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Well, if you've replaced it with something else then it's your own fault. **EITHER WAY** you need to edit the `postinst` script to resolve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't agree, and I think you are offering bad advice. Changing the `postinst` doesn't fix the problem, it works around it for one package installation, once: the problem will rear its head in other places, and crop up again as soon as you upgrade the PHP package (which will happen frequently with security updates).

Comment: The `postinst` isn't normally broken. Thousands of users can install and uninstall PHP just fine. He did something to break it, apparently install `busybox`, which I assume he did on purpose. He can either 1) revert 2) update postinst to account for his different system 3) cry. I assumed his preference was 2.

Comment: There are other, more sane options, one of which is outlined in my answer, another of which is outlined in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a recent Kali 1.1.0 VM install on Fusion 7.1.1.

Here's what sorted me out:

```
apt-update
aptitude reinstall coreutils
mv /usr/bin/readline /usr/bin/readline.old (leaves GNU /bin/readline as available, trash once completed)
update-grub
sed -i 's/BUSYBOX=y/BUSYBOX=n/' /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

I agree with jmtd, editing a postinst seems both overkill and kludgy.